# Importing a SQL file closes mysql command client

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to import a SQL database file around 88 MB into my local mysql server using mysql command line client with `mysql> source file.sql;`

As soon as I hit enter, the command line immediately closes. No error message, no nothing, it just shuts down. The .sql file is stored in `C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/bin`

I have tried searching the net for answers but I couldn't find anything.

*It's not a duplicate I've tried everything stated in the question, but when I run it the command line closes. It doesn't give any error and it doesn't save the database either.

Comment: Try asking on Database Administrators site